# Is Android Instant App different from app streaming?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

As from Google I/O 2016 key note, Google has [Introduced Android Instant Apps](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/05/android-instant-apps-evolving-apps.html?m=1)

This is pretty clear from the description that it is going to be possible to download a part of application (that is stream?) when it will be out for the developers to try it.

Couple of posts like [This one](http://www.recode.net/2016/5/18/11696010/google-instant-apps-deep-linking) quotes about Instant Apps :

> While this is different from Google's efforts to do app streaming inside search, it's in the same spirit — and gives Google similar access to previously walled-off data inside apps.

I am wondering how it is different from app streaming if the app is going to be installed partially with Android Instant Apps?

Any additional information about this new leap in android development will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module of the app gets downloaded inside a sandbox. As the user navigates to the boundaries of the app more app modules will be downloaded. You as a developer will need to determine when to prompt the user to download the full app. Note that the app state inside the sandbox will not automatically be transferred over when the user downloads the full app. Furthermore, whilst the instant app module(s) will be cached inside the sandbox there is no guaranteed persistence.

Comment: Great @davehenry . It would be nice if you could provide the source link with this info.

Comment: Documentation - https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Comment: Hmm, and how do you prompt the user to install the app? I mean ... do you just use a normal intent to open the app in the play store, or does the system have some sort of way of installing it directly from the instant app without going to the play store ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Instant Apps enables native Android applications to run in response to launching a URL, without installing the app. Instant apps can use many Android APIs and you use Android Studio to build them.

**How do they work?** When Google Play receives a request for a URL that matches an instant app, it sends the necessary code files to the Android device that sent the request. The device then runs the app.

**Note:** Android Instant Apps only work on Android devices running on Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher.
[Reference Android Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html)